# How to Solve undefined symbol error in JNI QTcreator.?

Tags: java, c++, netbeans, java-native-interface, qt-creator

I have written the sample c++ code and created shared library for this c++ code. Now i am trying to call SO file insight jni of qtcreator. I got this:

```
"/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libjni.so.1.0.0: undefined symbol: helloworld"
```

Steps I followed:

1. Created helloworld.so using netbeans.
2. Created JNI code using qtcreator.
3. helloworld function is placed insight jni code(Qtcreator).
4. Now try to call jni code using eclise(java)

I loaded `helloworld.so(netbeans)` and `jni.so(qtcreator)` insight `usr/local/lib` folder.

I got response from jni code using eclipse(java),But helloworld.so(Helloworld function) did not call insight jni code.I got above error.

How to solve above error?

How to call c++ so insite jni code?

Comment: A library called "helloworld.so" is odd, and I'm not surprised the linker doesn't find it. By convention it should be "libhelloworld.so" -- perhaps if you rename it, the linker will find it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..But helloworld.so already name as in libhelloworld.so. Even JNI did not recognise the c++ so.